# Installing ruby on rvm error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I'm following the guide on rvm to install on OSX Leopard:
http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

I have everything working up until I have to go 
rvm install 1.9.2

however I start getting errors when I run that command:

```
summer$ rvm install 1.9.2-p290
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/summer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

UPDATE: in regard to Deryls response:

error after the modifications:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/summer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

UPDATE:

I removed the - at the end and got:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/summer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ERROR: There was an error, please check /Users/summer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I also tried both variation of using the - (or not) at the end with --insecure instead of k, I get similar errors.

Comment: Have you tried to update your RVM installation? rvm get latest

Comment: I already have the latest version

Answer (score 3):

Instead of modifying the rvm script, you can fix the root-cause of the issue by updating your ca-bundle.crt file.  On certain Linux distros, the ca-bundle.crt file is way too old and thus doesn't know how to handle Github's SSL certificate.

What you can do is to locate the ca-bundle.crt on your system and then download and rename the cacert.pem from curl.haxx.se as ca-bundle.crt.  Now the RVM installer script should work correctly.

This is what I did:

```
cp /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt ~/ca-bundle.crt.old

sudo curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-b
undle.crt
```

This machine is an EC2 instance, running CentOS 5 and managed with Rightscale.  The location of your ca-bundle.crt on your system will probably be different, but there is only a few things Googling won't solve.

Answer (score 1):

The version of curl on Leopard is outdated. Follow beijingyoung's steps listed here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6103#issuecomment-1694558

Comment: I did a fresh install for curl, so I have the latest version

Answer (score 1):

You can also hand modify $rvm_path/scripts/fetch on line 61

```
fetch_command="curl -f -L --create-dirs -C - " # -s for silent
```

and change it to read

```
fetch_command="curl -f -L --create-dirs -C -k - " # -s for silent
```

What this does is tell curl not to care about any invalid certificates (you're not using one you had signed by a registered CA are you?) You can also add -s (as the # remark shows) in order to keep it quiet. Bear in mind that you will probably have to make this change again the next time you

```
rvm get head
```

to update your machine's RVM install. I will tale to Wayne about adding that as a permanent option if the detected platform is Leopard, however I do not believe this will go into the application as it creates a security concern for many users. (They prefer to see the errors and know there is a issue with certificates.)

Comment: hrmm attempt it again after removing the - at the end. (I think the s is missing but right now I want to see if it works correctly for you even if its verbose about it)